# Как считать одномерный массив из файла?

Tags: c++, файлы

Программа должна считывать массив из файла и отсортировать значения по возрастанию. Какие функции/классы можно использовать для считывания массива из файла и дальнейшней его сортировки?

Comment: Не знаете что делать _ как считать из файла или как сортировать?

Comment: как считать из файла

Comment: Да так же, как и из `cin`...

Comment: сначала открывайте файл для чтения (смотрите в примерах из интернета, как это делается)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все довольно просто. Для начала разбейте задание на небольшие подзадачи:

1. Открыть сам файл с массивом.
2. Считать оттуда числа.
3. Отсортировать массив.
4. Вывести на экран.

---

Работу с файлами можно реализовать с помощью [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream). Считывание производится оператором [`>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). Отсортировать массив можно с помощью [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). На экран выводим обычным [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout).

Если собрать все вместе, то получим что-то такое:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

auto read_numbers_from_file(std::ifstream& f)
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    for (int n; f >> n; )
        v.push_back(n);

    return v;
}

void print_vector(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (auto n : v)
        std::cout << n << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input_file("numbers.txt");

    if (input_file.is_open()) {
        /* Считываем числа из файла. */
        std::vector<int> numbers = read_numbers_from_file(input_file);

        /* Сортируем полученный вектор. */
        std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

        /* Печатаем его содержимое. */
        print_vector(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Оттуда.. ;) не от туда

Comment: во первых нет смысла обявлять эти функции как статические(они и так только для  main.cpp, ). Во вторых :  аргументом лучше сделать std::istream& (а вдруг понабоится читать не из файлового потока).  В третьих:  могли бы не писать код в функции, а сразу вернуть  std::vector<int>{std::istream_iterator<int>(f), std::istream_iterator<int>()};

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, во-первых, писать `static` имеет смысл, т. к. в таком случае имена функций не попадут в объектный файл (а вообще, это просто привычка). На счет третьего: для автора это будет бессмысленная строка кода, за объяснением которой он пойдет в комментарии. Не знаю, заметили вы или нет, но старался писать просто, используя самые примитивные вещи из C++.

Comment: @eanmos, теперь понятно, спасибо. Только не думаю, что если кто то знает что такое Range-based for loop  и  знаком со стандартными контейнерами, то для него будет какая то сложность в выражении, приведенной мной.  А что касается автору вопроса, то, насколько я понел,  ему  нужно выполнить действия с обычными массивами, но я могу и ошибатся...

Comment: @ヒミコ, спасибо, исправил :)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, будем надеятся, что автор все поймет. Хорошего дня вам :)

Comment: @eanmos Не понимаю, как здесь считываются данные, можете объяснить: auto read_numbers_from_file(std::ifstream& f)
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    for (int n; f >> n; )
        v.push_back(n);

    return v;
} Не понимаю, передаются сразу все числа или по одному ?

Comment: @Pups, мы считываем числа по-одному и добавляем их в вектор.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с путями и вообще с файловыми системами есть [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) работу с путями желательно строить через него.

**`std::filesystem::current_path() / "data"`** — укажет путь до файла который лежит рядом с бинарником Вашей программы.

**`std::filesystem::exists(path)`** — проверит существование файла. см `CheckAndGetFStream` ниже.

Далее открываете и проверяете файл на открытие.

**`std::ifstream::is_open`** — вернет `true` если файл успешно открылся.

Если вы уверенны в корректности данных (формат и содержание) Вы можете просто отдать конструктору вектору 2 итератора (итератор на начало файла и конец) (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

**`std::istream_iterator<int64_t> begin_file{in_stream}, end_file;`**

**`std::vector<int64_t> data(begin_file, end_file);`**

Если нет, то лучше читать по лексеме с обработкой ошибок а-ля (в таком случае если где-то появилось что-то отличное от `is_space(...)==true` оно будет игнорироваться и чтение пойдет дальше, а в первом случае закирпичится и данные за этим символом не будут прочтены)

```
std::vector<int64_t> data{};
int64_t val{0};
while (true) {
    if (in_stream.eof()) {
        break;
    }
    in_stream>> val;
    if (in_stream.fail()) {
        in_stream.clear();
        in_stream.ignore(1);
    } else {
        data.push_back(val);
    }
}
```

После чтения файла нужно проверить, прочиталось ли вообще хоть что-то)

Для сортировки есть [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) куда Вы можете указать `std::less` и `std::greater` в зависимости от того, как Вам надо отсортировать данные

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <filesystem>


std::ifstream CheckAndGetFStream(std::string file_name) {
    auto path{std::filesystem::current_path() / file_name};

    if (!std::filesystem::exists(path)) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Error : file not found"};
    }

    std::ifstream in_stream(path);

    if (!in_stream.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Error : file not open"};
    }

    return in_stream;
}


void CopyDataToStdout(std::vector<int64_t>& data) {
    std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


 std::vector<int64_t> ReadIntDataFromFileIt(std::string file_name) {

    auto in_stream{CheckAndGetFStream(file_name)};

    std::istream_iterator<int64_t> begin_file{in_stream}, end_file;

    std::vector<int64_t> data(begin_file, end_file);

    if (!data.size()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Error : file not read"};
    }

    std::cout << "Data : " << std::endl;
    std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int64_t>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return data;
 }


 std::vector<int64_t> ReadIntDataFromFileCheck(std::string file_name) {

    auto in_stream{CheckAndGetFStream(file_name)};

    std::vector<int64_t> data{};
    int64_t val{0};
    while (true) {
        if (in_stream.eof()) {
            break;
        }
        in_stream>> val;
        if (in_stream.fail()) {
            in_stream.clear();
            in_stream.ignore(1);
        } else {
            data.push_back(val);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Data : " << std::endl;
    CopyDataToStdout(data);

    return data;
 }


 void SortAndPrint(std::vector<int64_t>& data) {

    std::sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::less<int64_t>());

    std::cout << "Data after less sort : " << std::endl;
    CopyDataToStdout(data);

    std::sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::greater<int64_t>());

    std::cout << "Data after greater sort : " << std::endl;
    CopyDataToStdout(data);
 }


int main() {

    std::string file_name{"data"};

    try {
        auto data{ReadIntDataFromFileIt(file_name)};
        SortAndPrint(data);
        auto data2{ReadIntDataFromFileCheck(file_name)};
        SortAndPrint(data2);

    } catch (std::runtime_error& rt_excpt) {
        std::cerr << rt_excpt.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unkn err" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```